Can I legally use content from a CC-BY-SA-licensed wiki in an MIT-licensed video game?
Specifically, I'm talking about the Backrooms Fandom Wiki. Most if not all of the textual content (creative writing) on it is licensed under CC-BY-SA. However, if I want to make a video game based on the creative writing on that wiki, can I distribute the game under the MIT License?

This depends on what you mean by "based on".
Can you copy any text from the wiki? No, the only right you have to use that content is under CC-BY-SA, and that is incompatible with the much more permissive MIT license.
Can you do something more generally inspired by the content? Yes.
Where's the line between the two? That depends on the specifics; your lawyer may be able to give guidance but there are no bright lines as to what counts as a derivative work and what doesn't.

I will not be copying text directly from the wiki, only occasionally quoting it; however, considering that the forms of media are vastly different (one is a webpage while the other is a 3D video game with original assets), I think it should be fine. I will consult a lawyer to be sure, thank you.
